# LDA Gensim/Mallet documentation on alpha

Tags: gensim, lda, mallet, dirichlet

I'm a little bit confused about the comments to alpha in the documentation of LDA (Gensim).

In the "regular" Gensim LdaModel it says that if one sets alpha = 'asymmetric', Gensim uses a "fixed normalized asymmetric prior of 1.0 / topicno" (topicno is num_topics, right?!). But why it is called asymmetric? Isn't that the symmetric case? (see https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)

And whats the default number for alpha used by Mallet? 50? If so, why? As far as i know one should choose some value <1 to get good results.
(see https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.html)